# Rails pattern for controller with feed, sign in and sing up forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, design-patterns

I'm building a Rails app.

The first page in my app is either a feed (like in Facebook) or a sign in + sign up form (depending on whether user is logged in or not).

Currently I have a `FeedController` with `index` action that builds my first page. I have `signin` and `signup` partials that would be rendered into the `index.html.erb` page if user is not logged in.

I feel like my `FeedController` is overloaded with code, and I ignore all the rules of CRUD-design.

Is there a Rails pattern to deal with such cases? What is the best way to solve my problem and still adhere to the rules of CRUD-design?

Comment: Please add the code for your FeedController class.

Comment: What do you mean overloaded? Overloaded with what ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a `SessionController`with `new`, `create`, `destroy` actions. There will be also `new.html.erb` for signing in (creating session). As a result your `routes.rb` should be like:

---

```
get 'signup', to: 'users#new', as: 'signup'
get 'login', to: 'sessions#new', as: 'login'
get 'logout', to: 'sessions#destroy', as: 'logout'
root to: 'feeds#index'
```

And in `ApplicationController` should be a `before_filter` which redirects unauthorized user to sign in page.